# How to weight data in R

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Weighted Pearson's Correlation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460664/weighted-pearsons-correlation)

I have imported data from SPSS file into R. Now I need to run correlations on weighted data. Data file name is wave1.

If I write `cor(wave1)` it correlates all variables even weight variable and do not weight the data.

First, is it possible to weight data and then run analysis without including weight into it. For example correlation, linear model.

If it is not, how do I run correlation with weighted data in R?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460664/weighted-pearsons-correlation

Comment: Welcome to SO!  It's worth searching for similar questions before you ask your own, since duplicates are liable to be closed.

Comment: And check this: [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). The question @Roland above mentions is a good example of how to ask a question.

Comment: Unfortunately the accepted answer for the question referenced above was incorrect - I have just posted an alternative answer